# What is the standard workflow for applying conflicting patches?

Tags: diff, patch

This is a programming language and version control system agnostic question.

There is a source code tree and two patches X and Y. Each of them apply cleanly to the source code tree. But applying one of them (either X or Y first), then another one, results in second patch failing to apply (patches conflict).

Is my only option applying one of them (probably the biggest one, so most of work gets done automatically), then merging the other one by hand and resolving conflicts, or there are better tools/practices to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to avoid this situation from happening as there's no easy solution to merge.

In order to avoid, make small commits with their tests and push them to the source repository. Other guys in the team will be forced to pull the latest changes in order to commit their code, and this will ensure that nothing gets broken.

I encourage you to avoid having multiple teams manipulating the same part of the source code. Create a good structure and if possible break down the project into smaller projects.